# Add JSON object to JSON Array in a file using nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have 2 list of users in 2 different file.
what i want to achieve is to create a single .json file where all these users from 2 different files are in the form of json object in json file.

```
EX:
file1 : ["a1@test.com", "a2@test.com"]
file2 : ["b1@test.com", "b2@test.com"]
```

**final Json file:**

```
[
    {
       "email" : "a1@test.com"
    },
    {
       "email" : "a2@test.com"
    }
    .....
]
```

I am new to nodejs, can some one plese help in doing this.

what i have done so far to write in JSON file:

```
function createJSONAndWrite(email){
    var arrayList = Object();
    arrayList.email = email;

    jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
        obj.push(arrayList);
        jsonfile.writeFileSync(file, obj);
    });
}
```

This is not working

Please help me

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: which part is not working? What errors are you getting? Did you do some research on how to read/write to files using node.js? I'm sure there are plenty of resources to read about that topic

Comment: every time i read json file to append data, the data returned is empty, i think asynchronous behaviour of nodejs

Comment: it will be great if you create the array structure and then at last do a file write

Comment: i have 2 different files can create single Array structure

Answer (score 1):

Here's a completely new solution:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');

async function generateOutputFile() {
    const arrayOne = await fs.readJson(fileOne);
    const arrayTwo = await fs.readJson(fileTwo);
    const output = arrayOne.concat(arrayTwo).map(email => {email});
    await fs.writeJson(outputFile, output);
}
```

*Note that I'm using [`fs-extra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) instead of [`jsonfile`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile) because it simplifies the code a lot by providing Promise support (Node.js 8 required).*

My code ...

- asynchronously reads both files and [waits for that to finish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
- [concatenates both arrays into one array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- transforms the array items (`"a1@test.com"`) into objects with the `email` property using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- asynchronously writes the output to a file